# how to send data from serial port to printer?

Tags: cat, serial-port, echo, printer

I have a telephone system that is connected to my old Ubuntu machine and is receiving SMDR data from it.
Connected to `dev/lp0` is a dot matrix printer, phone system connected to `/dev/ttyS0`

Currently I am using the command `cat /dev/ttyS0 > /dev/lp0`.
This works somewhat but the smdr print has a cr and lf  commands for the printer already.  Cat send to make the printer feed an extra line. 
Is there a way to constantly `echo ttyS0` to `lp0` or something else I can do? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove postprocessing from `/dev/lp0`. Try the following:

```
(
stty -F /dev/lp0 -opost
cat /dev/ttyS0
) > /dev/lp0
```

Enclosing the two commands in a subshell and redirecting its output to `/dev/lp0` prevents the stty settings being reset to default when no process has `/dev/lp0` open anymore (inbetween the `stty` and the `cat`).

Perhaps you also need to change `/dev/ttyS0` settings, e.g. remove any input processing: `stty -F /dev/ttyS0 -icanon -echo min 8 time 1` (the `min 8 time 1` means that reads will return as soon as at least one byte is read and no further input is available after 1/10th of a second, or if more input becomes available reads will return after at most 8 bytes read).